# .NET Framework 4.5.2 not backwards compatible to 4.0.30319?

Tags: .net, frameworks

My application requires Framework 4.5.2.
When it's not installed, my setup installer will install it. This works great.

Now I've experienced a situation on clean Windows 7 computer where my application won't start telling me that it requires .NET Framework 4.0.30319.

Obviously some components of my app require this framework, but I thought that installing 4.5.2 would be sufficient. I thought it was backwards compatible and would remove the necessity for Framework 4.0.30319.

Is that not the case or which other culprit may I have stumbled into here?

Edit: It gets even worse: When I want to install Framework 4.0, it tells me that a newer version is already installed.

Edit 2:
I had the following 2 Frameworks installed:

```
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2, Version 4.5.51029
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (German), Version 4.5.51029
```

After I un-installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (German), Version 4.5.51029, my application started. I don't have any idea what goes on here.

Answer (score 0):

After a Windows update, it worked.
I didn't do anything else.